# variables within the Mail function in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to use a variable within the `Mail` function in Laravel 5 and it seems to be erased somehow.
Here is what I have:

```
public function SendEmail($data){


         Mail::send('emails.issue-found', $data, function ($message) {
         // dd($data);
        $message->from('me@myemail.com', 'my name');
        $message->subject('Alert!');
        $message->to($data['name']['email']);
    });
}
```

Maybe it sends the actual `$data`?
In the row `$message->to($data['name']['email']);` I get an error:

> Undefined variable: data

I tried to put `$data` in a different variable but that didn't work either.
Any help would be mush appreciated.

Comment: function ($message) use ($data)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined Variable Inside Mail::send in Laravel 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33755587/undefined-variable-inside-mailsend-in-laravel-5)

Answer (score 3):

Passing the `$data` variable as a parameter of the `Mail::send` function only makes it accessible to the email view. You have to utilise `use` to access data within the anonymous function:

```
public function SendEmail($data){
    Mail::send('emails.issue-found', $data, function ($message) use ($data) {
        $message->from('me@myemail.com', 'my name');
        $message->subject('Alert!');
        $message->to($data['name']['email']);
    });
}
```

You can read more about anonymous functions here: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Answer (score 2):

Like @haakym wrote, except the `use $data` needs to be `use ($data)`.

Like so -

```
public function SendEmail($data){
Mail::send('emails.issue-found', $data, function ($message) use ($data) {
    $message->from('me@myemail.com', 'my name');
    $message->subject('Alert!');
    $message->to($data['name']['email']);
});
```

}

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Oops glad you caught my mistake! Will update the answer.

Comment: Oh and you're welcome! Glad I could be of some help!